# AD returns computer object when searching for users

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I've just spent three hours figuring this out and hope someone can tell me what happened here.

I have AD code that searches for users. In our domain, usernames are similar to computernames (the convention is along the lines of first + last + computer name).

When I run the following query, I sometimes get a computer, sometimes I get a user:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(anr=username))
```

When I use SamAccountName instead of anr, I always get a user. I had to change my code to do this.

Is there any reason the anr query would override the objectClass query? (I would think this code is asking for users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. Computers derive from users in AD's class hierarchy. Use this filter and you'll be good.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(anr=username))
```